# Cannot connect to MongoDB Atlas from Google Cloud Run Docker Container

Tags: .net, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to get a simple proof of concept to work.  I have a .Net 3.1 web api that I have placed inside of a docker container.  Its the default weather forecast sample, with one twist: I save the weather information into a mongodb.  This works perfectly on my local machine. When I create the service in Cloud run and hit the URL I am getting the following errors in my log:

```
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST Connection id "0HMJ0CTI14V9O", Request id "0HMJ0CTI14V9O:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MSTSystem.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/ac-xxxxxx-shard-00-00.xxxxxx.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/ac-xxxxxx-shard-00-00.xxxxxx.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytes(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Dropbox.RemoveMessage(Int32 responseTo)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBuffer(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessage(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol1.Execute(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.HelloHelper.GetResult(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol1 helloProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.SendHello(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Default
2022-07-07 15:24:49.688 MST at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

On the cloud side I have created the VPC Peerless connection, white listed the CIDR for the mongo db atlas cluster.  On the Mongodb Atlas side I have connected successfully to my VPC Peerless connection and white listed the CIDR from the cloud side.

Things I have tried:

- Created a new VPC to use with everything in gcp.
- Created a serverless VPC Access on 10.8.0.0/28 (white listed this
  CIDR on the mongo side)
- Tried creating a Serverless Mongo Database on    atlas
- Added the sslsettings

  EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
- Added connection time out and poolsizes code
- altered my connection string with wrong values and got the same error
  messages (makes me think its something on my network side)
- Tried posting a question on the Discord MongoDB server (very nice
  people but couldn't help).

I am using .Net Core 3.1
MongoDB.Driver 2.16.1
Docker 20.10.16

**I am out of ideas and I am asking my people for help.**

**UPDATE**:
I changed the account type for Mongodb Atlas to the paid version so I could download the cluster logs.  Apparently it says that the client is disconnecting after authentications:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.111+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43664","uuid":"ab35b418-6519-xxxx-9854-d29f005e6f35","connectionId":488,"connectionCount":21}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.111+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn487","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43662","client":"conn487","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-go-driver","version":"v1.7.2+prerelease"},"os":{"type":"linux","architecture":"amd64"},"platform":"go1.17.10","application":{"name":"MongoDB Automation Agent v12.0.6.7562 (git: cddb628636c9576fed56ce13bdc0a3d24e65ca1c)"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.123+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn488","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43664","client":"conn488","doc":{"driver":{"name":"mongo-go-driver","version":"v1.7.2+prerelease"},"os":{"type":"linux","architecture":"amd64"},"platform":"go1.17.10","application":{"name":"MongoDB Automation Agent v12.0.6.7562 (git: cddb628636c9576fed56ce13bdc0a3d24e65ca1c)"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.133+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn488","msg":"Authentication succeeded","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"__system","authenticationDatabase":"local","remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43664","extraInfo":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.135+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn486","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":5410}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.135+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn487","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43662","uuid":"8d30489b-afce-xxxx-bd59-1d6d145f889e","connectionId":487,"connectionCount":20}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.136+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn486","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43660","uuid":"1b8c0b43-43df-xxxx-ab3c-08307275c057","connectionId":486,"connectionCount":19}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.137+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43666","uuid":"5016ad7f-324c-xxxx-81ea-819671f9a663","connectionId":489,"connectionCount":20}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.138+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"192.168.xxx.2:43668","uuid":"b7ff7c30-193c-xxxx-b961-b08806564447","connectionId":490,"connectionCount":21}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-10T06:12:03.138+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20883,   "ctx":"conn483","msg":"Interrupted operation as its client disconnected","attr":{"opId":5386}}
```

Does this look like its on the Cloud Run Side or the Mongo DB Atlas side?

Comment: Thank you Ferregina, I tried to add the block quote but the editor kept telling me that I had code that was not properly formatted and that I needed to format it before I could post.

Comment: Did you check your firewall rules? did you try to run your container in a VM ?

Comment: I have checked the firewall rules and made sure that the CIDR entries for the atlas cluster are listed for ingress.  I didn't know you could run your container in a VM, I will attempt to do that now.

Comment: I got the container to run in a VM, same error.  I white listed 0.0.0.0 on the mongo db side just incase I had the wrong IP (s), same error.  I changed it to a singleton for the connection, no joy.  I do not understand why this has to be so hard, 4 solid days of failure, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this eventually @Haggis777 ?
I'm in the same boat

Comment: I did not.  I ended up just running a VM with mongo on it till I had more time to troubleshoot it.  I wish you luck on your quest sir.